# Error on compiling Firemonkey Android APP

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

What is wrong with this code? Delphi 10.4 Compiler gives me

> Not enough actual parameters

Error is on:

```pascal
ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected := OnServiceConnected;
```

and

```pascal
ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected := OnServiceConnected;
```

Here is the code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.App,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os,
  FMX.Platform.Android,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure OnServiceConnected(name: JComponentName; Binder: JIBinder);
    procedure OnServiceDisconnected(name: JComponentName);
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.OnServiceConnected(name: JComponentName; Binder: JIBinder);
begin
  //
end;

procedure TForm1.OnServiceDisconnected(name: JComponentName);
begin
  //
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
  ServiceConnection: JServiceConnection;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setPackage(StringtoJString('com.xxx.xxxservice'));
  Intent.setAction(StringtoJString('com.xxx.xxxservice'));

  ServiceConnection := TJServiceConnection.Create;
  ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected := OnServiceConnected;            // Not enough actual parameters !!!
  ServiceConnection.onServiceDisconnected := OnServiceDisconnected;      // Not enough actual parameters !!!
  TAndroidHelper.Context.bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, TJContext.JavaClass.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
end;

end.
```

Comment: What is the type of `TJServiceConnection.OnServiceConnected`?

Comment: It is JServiceConnection interface:

  JServiceConnection = interface(IJavaInstance)
    ['{B1F97308-817B-4AC2-91CA-3C5FF72D4707}']
    procedure onBindingDied(name: JComponentName); cdecl;
    procedure onServiceConnected(name: JComponentName; service: JIBinder); 
cdecl;
    procedure onServiceDisconnected(name: JComponentName); cdecl;
  end;

Comment: That explains the error. You cannot assign a method pointer to the "result" of a procedure call. Hence, the compiler assume the RHS is intended to call `OnServiceConnected`, and then, indeed, two parameters are missing. I know nothing about this topic, but perhaps you are supposed to *implement* this interface yourself?

Comment: Any hint on how to implement this interface?

Comment: The documentation is pretty good, actually: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Implementing_Interfaces. (At least this applies to Win32. Again, I know almost nothing about Android!)

Comment: Where is the source code for TJServiceConnection? I don't find it in Delphi.

Comment: unit Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to write your own class that implements the `JServiceConnection` interface methods, and then pass an instance of that class to `bindService()`. Do not create an instance of the `TJServiceConnection` class

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using TLocalServiceConnection from the System.Android.Service unit? Incidentally, that class shows you exactly what you're trying to do.